# A method to store data in an offline application

Tags: javascript, android, html, offline

Currently this application which i have created, for mobiles and computers stores data offline. For example, the user can type data into a box click the save button, turn off his internet and load the data which was just stored for offline use. I want to revamp this feature, so that it will list offline news articles from ANY wesbsite, i dont care what site it is, as long as it shows news articles for offline use. Any ideas on what to do?

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline.manifest">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Offline test page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<p id="status">Online</p>

<h1>Off-line test page</h1>
<p>This page detects when the browser goes off-line and stores data locally.</p>

<form id="mainform" action="index.html" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Update data</legend>

<label>Data item 1: <input type="text" id="data1" name="data1" value="" /></label>

<button type="submit">Save Data</button>

</fieldset>
</form>

<p>Use File &gt; Work Offline in Firefox to switch online/offline modes.</p>
<p><a href="index.html">Refresh the page</a> in offline mode to reload data from store.</p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="offline.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
// page loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // form data saving
    $("#mainform").submit(lib.Save);

    // online/offline event handler
    if (window.sessionStorage) {
        lib.Net.ChangeStatus();
        $(window).bind('online offline', lib.Net.ChangeStatus);
    }

    // load data
    lib.Load();

});

// online/offline library
var lib = lib || {};

lib.Net = function() {

    var online = true;

    // is browser online?
    function Online() { return navigator.onLine; }

    // online/offline event
    function ChangeStatus() {
        if (online != Online()) {
            online = Online();
            var s = $("#status");
            s.text(online ? "Online" : "Offline");
            if (online) s.removeClass("offline");
            else s.addClass("offline");
        }
    }

    return {
        Online: Online,
        ChangeStatus: ChangeStatus
    };

}();

// save data online or offline
lib.Save = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (lib.Net.Online() || !window.sessionStorage) {

        // save data online
        alert("Data has been saved online.");

    }
    else {

        // save data offline
        $("#mainform input").each(function(i) {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
        });
        alert("Data has been saved offline.");

    }

};

// load data online or offline
lib.Load = function() {

    if (lib.Net.Online() || !window.sessionStorage) {

        // load data online
        alert("Currently online:\ndata could be loaded from server.");

    }
    else {

        // load data offline
        $("#mainform input").each(function(i) {
            this.value = window.sessionStorage.getItem(this.id);
        });
        alert("Data has been loaded from offline store.");

    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

What u are trying to do is making an app like Pocket?

What u need is saving the articles from different websites in html/css style or something else, like pdf files. Take the html/css and either save it or convert it to pdf and save the pdf. After that u can just load it in.

U'll have to use LocalDB or something like that for saving the links to your saved files.

Comment: LocalDB is a feature of Microsoft SQL Server, so it's not available in client-side web applications. A client-side application would use something like [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for offline storage.